# Why are line endings added to exported SoapUI TestSuites?

Tags: return, export, soapui, line-endings, test-suite

Whenever I export a full TestSuite from SoapUI 5.2.0, "\r" is added almost randomly to my test requests:

```
<![CDATA[<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">\r
   <soapenv:Header/>\r
   <soapenv:Body>\r
      <ns:getAllowableActions>\r
         <ns:repositoryId>${#TestCase#repositoryId}</ns:repositoryId>\r
         <ns:objectId>${#TestCase#folderId}</ns:objectId>\r
      </ns:getAllowableActions>\r
   </soapenv:Body>\r
</soapenv:Envelope>]]>
```

Any idea what caused this? Importing this in the newest version in SoapUI is not a problem, yet if I import it in any earlier version it will import the \r into the requests.

How can I make sure this doesn't happen anymore?

Comment: I have the same problem :( caused problem with collaboration with team

Comment: Hmm.. For now as workaround I always do a search on the document after I performed an export  and replace all ">\r"" with ">". Please, try that until someone might come up with a solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my earlier comment:

For now as workaround I always do a search on the document after I performed an export and replace all ">\r" with ">". Please, try that until someone might come up with a solution. :)